# Iterating over "this" in Java:

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration, this

I am trying to understand how the following iteration is working, in other words how can we iterate over the `this` (I have seen this implemented at someone else's program). The method `getEl` is part of a class `C` that implements Iterable. Class `C` itself does not have any containers of type `A`, but has a private variable of type `A`. Class `A` on the other hand has iterable containers (sets of type `A` and sets of another type `D`).

```
public void getEl() {
    for(A el : this) {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Comment: There's nothing magic happening here - you can iterate over any `Iterable`, so if `this` is `Iterable`, you can iterate over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class C implements `Iterable<A>`, which contains the method `iterator()` that returns an `Iterator<A>`.

You can use the enhanced for loop on any object that implements Iterable.

It's equivalent to :

```
Iterator<A> iter = this.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    A el = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate over `this` (whatever type it is) if `this` also implements [`Iterable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Answer (score 2):

`for ( : )` is just syntax sugar for calling `iterator()` on the given object, and using the returned iterator object to go through a set of elements (which is entirely determined by the implementation of said iterator). Since `this` is an instance of a class that implements `Iterable`, you would look at its `iterator()` method.

Mostly, it is confusing to see `this` being used here. However,

```
 C foo = this;
 for (A el : foo) {}
```

Is just the same.